Wrongly picking up the discard pile in Canasta
What is the penalty for picking up The discard pile in error.
For example, a player has two of the same face value cards but have not completed their initial melds points wise for the rd and even with the top card they wont reach the point threshold.

There is no penalty, the play is just undone and they would draw from the deck as they are supposed to. This is likely just a case of miscounting the points from the play.
This is how it is handled in various electronic versions I have played that let you attempt that even if you can't get enough points.

I have heard 200 point penalty and an auto re-deal of the whole round as it lets players know whats in their hands. Electronic games dont allow you to mistake pick up the discard pile. I tried and tested

And I have played versions that let you make that mistake. Also letting others know what is in your hand is a penalty.
